# Canvas strokeStyle thickness

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I've tried to google the subject but couldn't find anything useful.

So, is it possible to change the canvas `strokeStyle` thickness?
If so how do I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GrXjJ/)
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineWidth)